# Cannot expose custom class in Java application with interfaced plugin class support, Jar within a Jar

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have a server/client setup which communicate using websockets, they are both Spring Boot applications and the message classes used to communicate are held in a separate project "CommonClasses".

Both the Server and Client projects have the CommonClasses project on their build path which gives them access to the shared message types.

The Client will receive a message from the Server and action it before responding.
To date there have been a limited number of functions that the client can perform however the intention is to open this up to customers to design their own implementations.  To this end there is an applier interface which must be instanced and this I have done simply by adding the Client to the classpath of a new project, putting in my new implementation and using the classpath loader in the client to load this new jar and call the new methods.

This works if I have a vanilla method but not when I attempt to implement the actual interface which previously passed forth messages as detailed in CommonClasses.

I can see these classes if I unpack the client jar file and add the resulting CommonClasses jar file to my classpath however when I do this and try and cast the instanced object to my Interface type I get a java.lang.ClassCastException.

I have researched this on stack overflow and I have come to the conclusion that it is because although the client interface and the interface referenced in the new project have the same signature and project they are treated as different objects.  All because I had to extract the CommonClasses jar from the client jar.

What are my options?
I know I could create a new interface and use just plain java types and convert everything but this would be expensive and want to avoid this if atall possible.
Changing the existing projects build process is possible but to be avoided if possible.

This is what I have thus far:

```
    URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:C:\\customApplier.jar")};
    // Create a new URLClassLoader
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);
    // Load the target class
    Class<?> beanClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.test.Applier");
    // Create a new instance from the loaded class
    Constructor<?> constructor = beanClass.getConstructor();
    ApplierIn ob = (ApplierIn)constructor.newInstance();
```

The exception is thrown when trying to cast to (ApplierIn). Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Ok, give me a few moments will try and reword it

Comment: One thing that springs to mind is that if the Client.jar and Common.jar both contain the ```ApplierIn```  interface you could get a classcast exception.

Comment: Hi, Yes ApplierIn.class makes use of a parameter class file in a method declaration, that class file for Client.jar is loaded from the CommonClasses.jar internally.  For the new project I have both the Client.jar and CommonClasses.jar on the classpath giving access to both .class files, unfortunately at run time this does not work as they are different .class files...  I am not sure there is a solution without a big re-design.

Comment: This sounds strange. I have worked with dynamically loaded Jars before, and unless you have multiple versions of the class loaded by different class loaders, you should not have this issue. Otherwise you would have an issue whenever you implemented ```Comperator<String>``` in a jar, since both ```Comperator```and ```String```is found in the JRE jars.

Comment: You should be able to debug which classloader has been used to load the instance (set a breakpoint before the cast), if you compare ```ApplierIn.class.getClassLoader()``` to ```instance.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getClassLoader()``` if this is not the same class loader, then you have multiple ```ApplierIn```interfaces in your classpath.

Comment: Looking at the code again, it looks like you didn't set the parent classloader, you should probably use a constructor which does that. My guess is that you want to use ```ApplierIn.class.getClassLoader()``` as parent, unless you have created other dynamic classloaders.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, your absolutely right they are different class loaders:

    org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@266e06d5
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2

I shall do as you suggested and update shortly!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Klaus-Groenbaek was able to identify problem, it was indeed an incorrect Class Loader. So I changed it to call:

```
    private static void addCustomJar(URL fileUrl) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(ApplierIn.class.getClassLoader(), new Object[]{fileUrl});
}
```

In order to load the new jar file into my application. After that it turns out that the unpacked jar within a jar was not an issue!

Comment: Are you sure this is the right solution. It looks like you are adding an additional jar file to an already instantiated classloader (perhaps there is a reason addURL is protected)? If this is true it has the following implications. 1) Your classloader will continue to grow in size. 2) You will get in trouble if you deploy ```MyApplier``` and want to deploy an updated version. I think the correct solution is to create another classloader with the correct parent, so you can discard it when a module is updated.

Comment: Hi, yes this will be unusual behaviour, basically we have a product that works and does what it should, but we have partners that want to be able to add a custom implimentation, in future their implementation may make it into our codebase but for now the intention is to give them an interface and in our config allow them to specify a path to a jar and define a package name.

Comment: I have worked with modular frameworks like the one you are describing. Typically the modules are more than a single Jar file, as they will have 3rd party dependencies, otherwise you will have to be very specific about which libraries are provided by the container, and in which versions.